# Stacked bar charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

i need to create a chart similar to this: [link text](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/view/image/file/9678/name/sample.png)

Do you have any tips or ideas of a library that I could use? I've tried Google Charts but it's not as flexible as I need it to be.

Note that I cannot use a library that requires a third party library to view the charts (like flash or silverlight).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en). Although targeting .Net Framework 3.5 they can also be used by applications using .Net 2.0

Comment: Microsoft Chart Controls can do this, and has the added bonanza of being free.

Comment: I've looked into this for some time ago. Does this library use silverlight och flash for rendering?

Comment: A year later, i ended up using this :)

Answer (score 1):

We use dotNetCharting for all of our charting. It is pretty much capabable of doing most things.

It's not free though.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Looks very interesting. I'm diving into it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DundasWebChart. You can download from [Dundas Web Chart for ASP .Net](http://www.dundas.com/Products/Chart/NET/Editions/ASPEnt.aspx)